# Embedding a document into chromadb using langchain

Tags: python, django, langchain, chromadb

Im trying to embed a pdf document into a chromadb vector database using langchain in django. I want to do this using a PersistentClient but i'm experiencing that Chroma doesn't seem to save my documents.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
import chromadb

from ..functions.load_new_pdf import load_new_pdf
from ..functions.store_docs_vector import store_embeds
import sys

from ..models import Documents

from .BaseView import get_user, strip_user_email

from ..functions.llm import chosen_llm

from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import sys
import os
load_dotenv()

OPENAI_API_KEY =
 os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')


embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings()


llm = chosen_llm()


    def uploadDocument(self, request):

        user = get_user(request)
        base64_data = request.data.get('file')

        # Create a record of the document in the SQLite database.
        document = Documents.objects.create(name=request.data.get(
            "name"), user=user, content=base64_data)
        document.save()

        # Convert the pdf into a big string.
        cleaned_text, documents = load_new_pdf(document)

        # Initiliaze the persistent client. 
        client = chromadb.PersistentClient(path="../chroma")

        # Strip the user email from the '@' and '.' characters and get or create a new collection for it
        collection_name = strip_user_email(user.email)
        client.get_or_create_collection(collection_name)

        # Embed the documents into the database
        Chroma.from_documents(
            documents=documents, embedding=embedding,
            client=client)

        # Retrieve the collection from the database
        chroma_db = Chroma(collection_name=collection_name, embedding_function=embedding, client=client)

        print(chroma_db.get()["documents"], file=sys.stderr) # This is now [], why??
```

In the above code I'm trying to create a new collection based on the users email, then load the documents into natural language so that they can be stored inside the vector db, then actually store them into the chromadb database. After that i'm trying to fetch the data again and print the documents it stored, but for some reason these documents are an empty array `[]`. Why is that?

When I print the variables `documents`, `strip_user_email(user.email)`, `embedding` and `client`, they all seem to be valid.

Comment: what is the output of `client.list_collections()` ? does it return collections?